# Accumulate matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization

Consider the 'm' matrix:
Link to 'matrix.dat':  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1COdMCCBKq85vMDj6Jrb2qqoUlE9eTk6w?usp=sharing

```
m = Import["matrix.dat"];
```

[image]
Let's define 'area accumulation' for matrices as follows:

```
m1=Accumulate[Accumulate /@ m];
```

[image]

How to add a condition so that the cumulative is only for elements other than zero? (so that the zero elements remain zeros)?
It would be good if the code was fast because I will do it for many matrices :)

Comment: Q: something like picking the non-zero entries and then `Accumulate` over those? Something like `Accumulate[SparseArray[m]["NonzeroValues"]]` or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Please provide a programmatic way to access your data. People should not need to fill out forms or sign up for services to reproduce your code. See [this Q&A about how to *Upload large amounts of data more easily*](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397) in [meta].

Answer (score 11):

If the input matrix `sa` is numeric, you can multiply the accumulated versions with `Unitize[sa]`. For example,

```
SeedRandom[1]
sa = SparseArray @ RandomChoice[{3, 1, 1, 1} -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, {7, 7}]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm[sa]
```

[image]

```
sa0 = Unitize[sa] (Accumulate /@ sa);


MatrixForm[sa0]
```

[image]

```
sa1 = Unitize[sa] Accumulate[sa0];

MatrixForm[sa1]
```

[image]

If the input matrix may have non-numeric elements use `saUnitize` instead of `Unitize` where

```
ClearAll[saUnitize]
saUnitize = SparseArray[#["NonzeroPositions"] -> 1, Dimensions @ #] &;
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1]

sb = SparseArray @ RandomChoice[{3, 1, 1, 1} -> {0, a, b, 3}, {7, 7}];

MatrixForm[sb]
```

[image]

```
sb0 = saUnitize[sb] (Accumulate /@ sb);

MatrixForm[sb0]
```

[image]

```
sb1 = saUnitize[sb] Accumulate[sb0];

MatrixForm[sb1]
```

[image]

**Update:**

Combining the steps into a single function:

```
ClearAll[accumulateNonzeroValues]

accumulateNonzeroValues = (saUnitize[sa] # &) @* Accumulate @* 
 (saUnitize[sa] # &) @* Map[Accumulate];


accumulateNonzeroValues @ sa == sa1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
accumulateNonzeroValues @ sb == sb1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively, you can also use a combination of `SubsetMap` + `Fold` + `Accumulate` as follows:

```
foldAccumulate[s_SparseArray] := 
    Module[{pos = Join @@ (GatherBy[s["NonzeroPositions"], #] & /@ {First, Last})}, 
      Fold[SubsetMap[Accumulate, #, #2] &, s,  pos]];


foldAccumulate @ sa == sa1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
foldAccumulate @ sb == sb1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to skip String, Symbols and missing values:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dt = SparseArray @ RandomChoice[{3, 1, 1, 1} -> {1, "a", Missing[_], 3}, {7, 7}] // Normal;

skip[v_?VectorQ] :=
 Module[{as, st, nm},
  as = AssociationThread[Range @ Length[v] -> v];
  st = Select[as, MatchQ[_String | _Symbol | _Missing]];
  nm = Select[as, NumberQ];
  <|Thread[Keys[nm] -> Accumulate @ Values[nm]], st|> // KeySort // Values]
```

Strangely, `Accumulate` doesn't know `Association`s (other functions like `MovingAverage` do).

```
Block[{set = Dataset[#, ItemSize -> 4] &},
 Row[{dt // set, " \[DoubleLongRightArrow] ", skip /@ dt // set}]]
```

[image]